# Why this error Exception print Connection refused on running

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

look at this loop. I wanted to make a small port scanner example.

```
for (int port = 1; port <= 65300; port++) {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", port)){
        socket.close();
        System.out.println("Port " + port + " Listen.");
    } catch (UnknownHostException uhe){
        System.out.println(uhe.toString());
        break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
    }
}
```

when I write `System.out.println(e.toString());` code print:

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

but when I delete it, code run well. tell me why it's happening if you know.

thanks

Comment: `System.out.println(e.toString());` prints the exception message when you delete the message that was not printed, but the exception still happens just you are not printing it. If you are confused about why "Something went wrong." was not printed you need to understand how exception catch works check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191745/exception-hierarchy-try-multi-catch

Comment: so what is my code's problem? when I remove that exception, I getting error on ```Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", port)```

Comment: You mean when you remove the catch block?

Comment: yes, when removing ```catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                break;
            }```

Comment: Thats because `new Socket("localhost", port)` throws two checked exception `UnknownHostException` and `IOException` you must explicitly handle these exception in you code . you are doing it for `UnknownHostException` but not for `IOException` since `Exception` is the super class for `IOException` when you add catch block with `Exception` which handles `IOException`

Comment: For better understanding of how exception works in java check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exceptions-in-java/

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, but I getting error after new update. i'm not sure if you mean it or not. but again I get ``` java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)``` error

Comment: and again when I delete IOException block, program working without any situations

Comment: You should _expect_ to see "connection refused" exceptions, as it's very unlikely that _every_ port on your computer has a server listening for and accepting connections. See the [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6876266/6395627) Q&A for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to tell you this but, the way you are trying to this will take what feels like *forever* to go through 65535 ports. Try setting a timeout on the Socket connection for any ports to at least speed up the process somewhat...something like perhaps 50 milliseconds. I suppose it depends upon the system you have. You can do this by using the [Socket#connect()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-socket-connect-method) method. Now, an IOException like `connect timed out`, `Permission denied:` (or `Connection refused`) basically means the port is **closed** or simply **not available** (which to you, may as well be considered as closed). Ports that generate an exception message of `Permission denied:` or `Connection refused` would be used by either System Hardware or Software and protected for their specific use only.

In my opinion, the best thing to do is to run the scan thought several [ExecutorService](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial) threads (like 3000 perhaps) to get the job done in maybe 30 to 40 seconds or so. Yes...your box will pump a little more blood for a bit, but, it beats waiting *all day* for the port scan to complete.

I would suggest that you don't display closed or unavailable ports during scanning...it's a waste of time. Sending output to a Console Window takes a **lot** of unnecessary processing time. Just store open ports in a Collection of some sort then display that collection of open ports to the Console (or whatever) when the port scanning is done. The runnable demo code below makes use of a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) so that the open port numbers inserted into the map remain in insertion order.

Unless you modify the code to run through several threads, I would suggest you set the `portEnd` int variable to 1000 (or 2000) to get a good idea how long a scan of 65000 ports will take. It should be enough to feed you something for results (I hope).

Here is the runnable demo code. Be sure to read the comments within:

```
final int timeout = 50;         // Socket Connection timeout in milliseconds
final int portStart = 1;        // 1 to 65535
final int portEnd = 65535;      // 1 to 65535 
final String ip = "127.0.0.1";  // Local IP.
java.util.LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> openPorts = new java.util.LinkedHashMap<>();
    
System.out.println("Scanning Ports: " + portStart + " To " + portEnd + ". Please Wait!");
System.out.print("Finished Scanning Ports Up To: -> ");
for (int port = portStart; port <= portEnd; port++) {
    /* This increases the Scan time but at least 
       it tells you that something is happenning:  */
    if (port % 100 == 0) {
        System.out.print(port + " ");
    }
    try (java.net.Socket socket = new java.net.Socket()) {
        // Open a connection to the current port Number:
        socket.connect(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(ip, port), timeout);
        // If successful, then the port is Open. If not, an Exception occurs.
        openPorts.put(port, "is Open!");
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        /* This takes time to process as well. It's only here 
           if for some reason something critical happens:  */
        String errMsg = ex.getMessage().toLowerCase(); 
        if (!errMsg.contains("connect timed out") && 
                    !errMsg.contains("permission denied:") && 
                    !errMsg.contains("connection refused")) {
            System.out.println("Port: " + port + " -> *** " 
                                 + ex.getMessage() + " ***"); 
        }
    }
}
    
// Display open ports in Console Window:
System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());
System.out.println("Port Scan Results - Open Ports:");
System.out.println("===============================");
    
// Read the LinkedHashMap:
for (java.util.Map.Entry<Integer, String> mapElement : openPorts.entrySet()) { 
    Integer keyPort = mapElement.getKey(); 

    // Finding the value using getValue() method: 
    String openClosed = mapElement.getValue(); 

    // Print the key-value pairs the way we want:
    System.out.println(String.format("Port #%-6d %-8s", keyPort, openClosed)); 
}
```

Comment: I copied and past your code, but again get ```Connection refused (Connection refused)``` error, so can this error happening because of some problem in system? and something else, it's just happening when I using loop, but in scanning one port, it's not problem.

Comment: @SaeedKiarsiZadeh Which port throws the "connection refused" exception? Why do you expect connecting to that particular port should succeed?

Comment: System hardware (or software) has most likely protected that port (and most likely other ports) for its own specific use. It would be the same as `Permission Denied`. Consider it a **Closed Port** to you and add the message to the `IOException` block, for example: `String errMsg = ex.getMessage().toLowerCase(); if (!errMsg.contains("connect timed out") && !errMsg.contains("permission denied:") && !errMsg.contains("connection refused")) { System.out.println("Port: " + port + " -> *** " + ex.getMessage() + " ***"); }`.